# Oracle/SQL: Check If Trigger Enabled/Disabled

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

How do you check if a specific trigger is enabled or disabled in Oracle/SQL?

The following specifies if my trigger is valid or not -- but not enabled or disabled

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'the_trigger_name';
```

My Oracle Database version: 12c - Enterprise Edition v12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

---

I have checked StackOverflow and came across the following posts, but didn't find an answer specific to Oracle/SQL:

- [SQL Server: check whether a Trigger is Enabled or Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136937/sql-server-check-whether-a-trigger-is-enabled-or-disabled)
- [ORACLE SQL Status check trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246317/oracle-sql-status-check-trigger)
- [How to check if a trigger is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120900/how-to-check-if-a-trigger-is-invalid)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`user_triggers` is the table where all triggers created, specific to the schema, are located.

So,

```
SELECT STATUS FROM USER_TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = 'the_trigger_name';
```

will fetch the status of either `ENABLED` or `DISABLED`.

Also, to fetch ALL triggers and their statuses--

```
SELECT TRIGGER_NAME, STATUS FROM USER_TRIGGERS;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query also worked for me:

```
SELECT trigger_name,status
FROM dba_triggers
WHERE trigger_name = upper ('TRIGGERNAME');
```